# What is the meaning of "being on the low side"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

For example :

> Going freelance nowadays is a path many designers and developers take, not only because of job vacancies **being on the low side**, but also because there are some clear advantages to it.

So what is the meaning of being on the low side?

Comment: *on the low side* is a casual, colloquial way of saying "relatively few".

Comment: @TRomano: Indeed. But *relatively* is very important there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is idiomatic, alluding to reading a meter for the quantity being measured. Imagine there was a gauge like a fuel gauge in a car that measured the number of job vacancies, and the gauge included a shaded area where there were the "right" number of job vacancies. "On the low side" would suggest that the gauge is at, or slightly below, the shaded area. There is an acceptable range, which has two sides, and the quantity is at the low side. It implies that there are fewer that would be desirable, but not necessarily too few.

"On the high side" can be used similarly to mean that there are more of something than would be desirable, but not so much as to be dangerous or incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

It means that there aren't a lot of full time jobs.

Comment: So "being on the low side" means that there is a little bit of something?

Comment: @Mostafa36a2 yes.

Comment: @Mostafa 36a2: Not really. It means *more accurately described as **low** rather than **high***. If your coal delivery was [a bit] on the low side, that doesn't mean you only got a little bit of coal - it means you got a little bit *less* than you ordered.

Comment: I'd say a substantially lower amount than desired or expected. If rain has been on the low side, you may be gearing up for a drought.

Comment: If it were less than substantial, we'd say "a bit on the low side" or "a little on the low side". But unqualified, it's substantial.

Answer (score 0):

Idiomatic *on the **low** side* alludes to *not* being on the "opposite" side, but unless specifically modified by an intensifier such as [***well*** on the high side](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22well%20on%20the%20high%20side%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) it normally means *just slightly more XXX than [not] XXX*. Thus, [*on the expensive side*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20the%20expensive%20side%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) implies *somewhat expensive, but not ruinously so*.

So if you tell the waiter that your pea and ham soup is [*on the salty side*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22on%20the%20salty%20side%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) he'll probably just offer you a glass of water (he won't assume you're complaining that it's too salty to eat at all).

Another related idiomatically common use of this type of ***side*** is...

> *Don't be so pessimistic! Why don't you [look on the bright side?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22look%20on%20the%20bright%20side%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)*

...where the usage always implies *Be optimistic **rather than pessimistic***.